# How to pass a single quote around a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a `javascript` code as shown below in which I want to pass a single quote around a javascript variable `attribute`.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make at Line A so that I am able to pass a javascript variable in a single quote.

At Line A, I did this `'${attribute}'` but I am getting an error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

```js
function deleteAttribute(attribute) {
  if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete  \`'${attribute}'\`  ?')){  // Line A         
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'abc.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            attribute: attribute
        },
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: If you put the whole string in double-quotes or back-quotes you don't have to do anything special for the embedded single-quotes.

Comment: That is not how template literals work.  It should look like `confirm(\`Are you sure you want to delete  '${attribute}'?\`)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're *trying* to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but have over-complicated it:

```
confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete  '${attribute}'  ?`)
```

Note the use of back-ticks around the whole template literal, which syntactically allows you to use any quotes you like within the literal itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the whole string inside backticks and then you don't have to 'escape' your single quotes anymore.

```
confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete  '${attribute}'  ?`)
```

Comment: This does not produce the desired result; it uses the string "TEST" instead of the variable `attribute`

Comment: Replace the TEST with ${attribute} and it will, this is literally your code but with fixed backticks.